# .htaccess direct links routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration

I am using front page controller and route all request to index.php with .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -!f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -!d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But this is cfg doesn't work with direct links (like http://example.ru/index.html ) and open this .html file, **but i need to even in this case, routing to the index.php**. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Below should work by redirecting all to index.php using ^.*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```